# Read csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My file.csv:

```
1
2
3
7
```

I need to convert this file to list like:

`['str-1', 'str-2', 'str-3', 'str-7']`

For this I have done:

```
import csv

data = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    data.append(f"str-{row}")
```

When I see the result of this lines I got:

`['str-['1']', 'str-['2']', 'str-['3']', 'str-['7']']`

What should I add to get the array that I need?

Comment: `data.append(f"str-{row[0]}")`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `csv` for this:

```
data = []
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for row in f:
        data.append(f"str-{row.strip()}")
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    data = [f"str-{row.strip()}" for row in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

data = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append("str-"+row[0])

print(data)

>> ['str-1', 'str-2', 'str-3', 'str-7']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to

```
import csv

data = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    [row] = row
    data.append(f"str-{row}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `pandas` to read `csv` file instead of reading line by line followed by adding a prefix to each element of a column as folows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", names=["col_0"])
data = ("str-" + df["col_0"].astype(str)).tolist()
```

Comment: code-only answers are considered low-quality. Try to add some explanation as to *how* and *why* this code answers the question. Some reference links can also add to the quality of your answer